# Laravel: How to initiate global libraries

Tags: php, laravel

I have
app/Libraries/Cart.php
app/Libraries/Currency.php
app/Libraries/SomeOther1.php
app/Libraries/SomeOther2.php
...

In all my controllers, I don't want to "use" and declare.
I don't want this:

```
<?php
namespace App\PathToFolder;

use App\Libraries\Cart;
use App\Libraries\Currency;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
  public someFunction()
  {
    $this->cart = new Cart;
    $this->cart->add(...);
    $this->cart->remove(...);
    $this->cart->clear(...);

    $this->currency = new Currency;
    $this->currency->format(...);
  }
```

I want this

```
<?php
namespace App\PathToFolder;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
  public someFunction()
  {
    $this->cart->add(...);
    $this->cart->remove(...);
    $this->cart->clear(...);
    $this->currency->format(...);
  }
```

There are no lines of "use" and "new". How to do? 
service provider? middleware?

This is also acceptable:

```
$this->library->cart->add(...);  
$this->library->cart->remove(...);  
$this->library->cart->clear(...);  
$this->library->currency->format(...);
```

Comment: you can use traits for this, but in the traits you gotta add `use ...`, lemme know if you want this and i can instruct you on how to do it

Comment: you have to use one 'use' when using repository function

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code without `use`. Add the namespace in instantiation instead.

```
<?php
namespace App\PathToFolder;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
  public someFunction()
  {
    $this->cart = new \App\Libraries\Cart;
    $this->cart->add(...);
    $this->cart->remove(...);
    $this->cart->clear(...);

    $this->currency = new \App\Libraries\Currency;
    $this->currency->format(...);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

usually i will do helper class where you don't need to load your massive init function in your controller or base controller

I created new Folder call Helpers and create new class name `helpers.php`

under autoload in composer.json, add your helper class in it..

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "files": ["app/Helpers/helpers.php"]
},
```

run `composer dumpautoload`

and in helper.php class.. see sample below

```
if (! function_exists('get_cart')) {

    function get_cart()
    {
       return new Cart();
    }
}
```

usage:

`get_cart()->add(...);`
`get_cart()->remove(...);`

**OR**

IF you dont want to use helper class. Just do static class

usage:

`Cart::add(...)`
`Cart::remove(...)`

**OR**

use **Trait** but still you are using **`$this`** in `$this->cart->add`

Answer (score 0):

There is one more below way to achieve this other then using traits or composer file as mentioned by others.

You can declare and initialize varible in parent controller and use it.

For Example,

Your parent controller a per your code

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
 use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
 use App\Libraries\Cart;
 use App\Libraries\Currency;

 class Controller extends BaseController
 {
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
    private $cart;
    private $currency;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //blockio init
        $this->cart = new Cart;
        $this->currency = new Currency; 
    }

 }
```

Now you can you this function in your controller like this

```
<?php
namespace App\PathToFolder;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
  public someFunction()
  {
    $this->cart->add(...);
    $this->cart->remove(...);
    $this->cart->clear(...);
    $this->currency->format(...);
  }
```